# Detect quantity of words and set as function in feature enginering task

Tags: python, string, count

I'm a beginner in python and I'm trying to set a model which would check if the address is company's or private person's. I've done with company indicators,

but I'm stuck at the point where I want to set that in case there are <2 words or >2 words in the 'Name' field it is TRUE in the code below:

```
df['Feat_1'] = df['Name'].apply(lambda x: "UAB" in x)
df['Feat_2'] = df['Name'].apply(lambda x: "AB" in x)
df['Feat_3'] = df['Name'].apply(lambda x: "MB" in x)
df['Feat_4'] = df['Name'].apply(lambda x: "II" in x)
df['Feat_5'] = df['Name'].apply(lambda x: "IĮ" in x)
df['Feat_6'] = df['Name'].apply(lambda x: "SB" in x)
df['Feat_7'] = df['Name'].apply(lambda x: **if len(['Name'.split()]) <2** <--???? in x)
df.head()
```

Example data:

```
Name            Street          City              
UAB 3 berzeliai Testine g. 1    Vilnius
UAB ACC         Terminalo g. 8  Biruliskes, Kauno Raj
ACC             Terminalo g. 8  Biruliskes, Kauno Raj
ACME            Terminalo g. 8  Biruliskes, Kauno Raj
IĮ Rododendras  Testine g. 9    Biruliskes, Kauno Raj
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

General piece of advice: never ever use `apply`. Well, sometimes you have to. But at least, do it once all other options (but for loop over rows: that is even worse) have been ruled out. The whole point of libraries like pandas is to be able to code on big datasets using a slow language like python (which is impressively fast for an interpreted high level language, but yet, it is very slow) while keeping the code fast. Because processing is done by batch, inside pandas code (which is not pure python).
That is ruined if you iterate over the rows in python; in such case, there is not point in not just using dictionaries. And `apply`, most of the time, are just a fancier way to iterate over the rows.

In your case, my rand means: "don't compute `"UAB" in x` for all x in your dataframe, when you can ask pandas to do that.

```py
df['Feat_1'] = df['Name'].str.contains("UAB")
```

Taking advantage of pandas vectorization capabilities.

Likewise (and that is, finally, an answer to your initial question): don't use `apply` to count words, when you could

```py
df['Feat_7'] = df['Name'].str.split().str.len()
```

Note `.str` means that target data is considered to be a string and you use method available on string on it. Which is logical for my 2 first usage (`.str.contains("UAB")` and `.str.split()`) but makes it strange for my third (`.str.len()`) since that one is applied on the result of `split`, that is on a list, not a string. Doesn't matter. The point is, like strings, list have a length, so it works. Exactly like you could access the second word of that list the way you would access the second char of a string: by calling `.str[1]`